# How to get a pod_name/container_id by its ip address on the host without using kubectl?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I would like find a way to inspect the container by eth0 ip of the pod.

What I tried:

```bash
target="1.1.1.1"
for container in $(docker ps -q); do
ip=$(docker exec -it $container sh -c 'ip -4 addr show eth0' | grep -oP '(?<=inet\s)\d+(\.\d+){3}' | xargs)
if [[ $ip = "$target" ]]
then
echo $container
fi
done
```

It works. But I wonder if there is other ways to make it without using `kubectl`

Comment: The container-private IP addresses are basically useless and there's never a reason to look them up.  (The only context you can use them from outside a container is on native Linux, from the same host only, directly using the Docker engine and not Docker Desktop or Kubernetes.)  Why do you think you need this address?  Docker and Kubernetes have somewhat different network setups, is your use case specific to one or the other?

Comment: Please have a look at this [document](https://www.tutorialworks.com/kubernetes-pod-ip/)